# Действительные числа через запятую в массив

Tags: java, поиск, числа, строки, double

Как оперировать вещественными числами из строки, разделенной запятыми?

У меня есть код для целых чисел, без разделителей (Пример 241-3234-2340-35011110-3). Мне нужно его адаптировать для действительных чисел, или получить совет как их обрабатывать.

Код предназначен для поиска наименьшей подпоследовательности.

Ввод адаптированного кода - -4.44,-5.525,-2.30,1,-2.01,-2.363,44.5,-2.344,-2.3,-4.35

Вывод - -2.01,-2.363 (тк она самая короткая)

Если встречаются подстроки одинаковой длины, то выбирается большая по сумме.

```
    public static int getMinimumValue(String inValue){
    boolean minusTrigger = false;//фильтр
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("Входные значения : " + inValue);
    for (int i = 0; i < inValue.length(); i++){
        switch (inValue.charAt(i)){
            case '-':
                minusTrigger = true;
                break;
            case '0':
                minusTrigger = false;
                //проверка на вставку 0
                if (buffer.length() > 0 &&
                        buffer.charAt(buffer.length() - 1) != '0'){
                    buffer.append('0');
                }
                break;
        }
        if (!minusTrigger && inValue.charAt(i) >= 49 && inValue.charAt(i) <= 57){
            buffer.append(inValue.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Значения после фильтра : " + buffer);

    String[] arrayValues = buffer.toString().split("0");

    try {
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(String value: arrayValues){
            int intBuffer = Integer.parseInt(value);
            minValue = intBuffer < minValue ? intBuffer : minValue;
        }
        return minValue;
    }
    catch(Exception x){
        System.out.println("Невозможно найти значения больше 0");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду как

> -4.44,-5.525,-2.30,1,-2.01,-2.363,44.5,-2.344,-2.3,-4.35

Преобразовать в массив типа `String`, то надо как-то так:

```
String[] arr = "-4.44,-5.525,-2.30,1,-2.01,-2.363,44.5,-2.344,-2.3,-4.35".split(",");
```

Comment: Это то понятно . Адаптации требует          try {
            double minValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            for(String value: arrayValues){
                double doubleBuffer = Double.parseDouble(value);System.out.println(doubleBuffer);
                minValue = doubleBuffer < minValue ? doubleBuffer : minValue;// если buffer меньше minValue, то он становится новым minValue
            }
            return minValue; //возвращаем результат
        }

Comment: @Fierus, мне всё ещё сложно понять в чём именно ваша проблема. Вам надо строку в Doble преобразовать?